# How to close dialog box which is opened by jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a webpage in which I open a dialog box, which shows another webpage. When I click on the submit button on this child webpage, it is loaded in the browser window.

Here is the whole synopsis:

On the parent page, I have a div which loads the child.

```
<div id="divMyDialog" title="Child Dialog Title">
</div>
```

In a jQuery file, I have the following:

```
$("#divMyDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    bgiframe: true,
    width: 800,
    height: 400,
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false
    });

function OpenDialog(FirstID, SecondID) {
    $("#divMyDialog").dialog("open").load("ChildPage.aspx?FirstID=" + FirstID+ "&SecondID=" + SecondID);
}
```

Now, once I click on an asp:button in ChildPage.aspx (after a database action), I want ChildPage.aspx to show an alert and then close. Instead, what is happening is that it shows the alert correctly, and then loads ChildPage.aspx in the browser.

For the alert, I have this in the OnClick event for that asp:button:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "showalert", "<script>CloseMyDialog();</script>");
```

To close ChildPage.aspx dialog, I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CloseMyDialog() {
        parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Please let me know if you need any more clarification. I have already tried many things, but so far none worked correctly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are loading the content, which does not mean it's an iFrame, you are loading the content of the page into #divMyDialog. So you don't have to do `parent.$.fn`. Also if you want to close the dialog you can do something like:

```
$("#divMyDialog").dialog("close");
```

And close all dialogs

```
$(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close");
```

Answer (score 2):

This closes a jQuery dialog:

```
$("#divMyDialog").dialog('close')
```

Comment: This loads ChildPage.aspx in the browser window. I have already tried this.

Answer (score 1):

You must load child page into an iframe. You can use fancybox:

```
$(".my-link").fancybox({'type':'iframe'});
```

http://moleskinformatico.blogspot.com/2011/11/llamar-funcion-de-ventana-padre-desde.html

Or you can do this:

```
 $(".my-link").click(function(){
 e.preventDefault();
 $this = $(this);
 $('<iframe id="site" src="' + this.href + '" />').dialog({
    width: 800,
    height: 400,
    modal: true

 });//dialog
});//click
```

http://blogs.antartec.com/desarrolloweb/2010/05/usando-jquery-dialog-con-iframe/

html:

```
<a hre="childPage.html" class="my-link">show-dialog</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop the submit process of the button.  This can be done by returning false on the onclick() button function.

Comment: I am already returning false. Do you mean the event for server side button?

Answer (score 0):

ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.GetType(), "closedialog", "$(function(){$('#dialog').dialog('close');});", True)